# Unicode Issue with Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, unicode, utf-8

Here goes the path I follow. 
1. User enters text in html editor, tiny mce edtitor.
2. that text is uploaded to Server side MVC controller
3. Controller use following line to write that HTML content (string) to a temp location on server
           new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(HtmlContent))
4. That file in temp location (in another step) is then used to get a byte[] of the contents
5. In the last step byte[] is send via stored procedure to database to a column field of type varbinary.
Now the problem is that when I read that varbinary back to byte[] and send it to browser using the following line of MVC with MIME type text/HTML. 
File(attachmentFile.BinaryData, mimeType, pFileName);
The file downloads and opens correctly in both IE and Firefox but not in chrome. I don't know what the issue is with chrome

Comment: UTF-8 is Unicode. Be specific about encodings: do you mean UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, or something else? And you really need to provide some concrete data, like start of the byte stream and the expected content of the HTML file.

Comment: Here goes the path I follow.
1. User enters text in html editor, tiny mce edtitor.